# How can I convert from a ByteString to a positive Integer

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I am trying to generate large random prime numbers (1024 bit-ish) so I need a way to generate large positive random numbers.

I began with `System.Random` but want to move to `Crypto.Random` from the `crypto-api` package.

The `Crypto.Random` only produces bytestrings, so I need a way to convert to an `Integer` type. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283119/how-to-convert-a-integer-to-a-bytestring-in-haskell?

Comment: @Thomas, I saw that, it's converting in the other direction and I had some trouble using `Data.Binary`. I can easily convert `Integer` types to bytestrings, but often converting from random bytestrings to `Integer` type causes an error. I don't know the internal representation of `Integer` but I assume generating random bytes can make invalid numbers.

Comment: @user668074 The [`Binary` instance for `Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.5.1/docs/src/Data.Binary.Class.html#line-311) writes a tag for whether it's a small integer that fits in a few bytes or a big one that is in many bytes, and for large integers writes a sign byte and a list of bytes preceded with a length; if the length doesn't match the number of bytes you'd get an error.

Comment: @Cirdec, thank you, I wasn't sure how Integers were represented. Do you know how the Natural integer type is represented?

Comment: The [`Binary` instance for `Natural`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.5.1/docs/src/Data.Binary.Class.html#line-368) is in the same file. Neither of these is how they're represented in memory. Both end up reading a list of bytes and folding it one byte at a time. Instead of mucking around in formatting your byte string into one of these formats, fold it yourself as shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47050983/414413).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without poking around in the internals of [`GHC.Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1/docs/GHC-Integer.html) you can fold the bytestring into an `Integer` one byte at a time.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Bits

fromBytes :: ByteString -> Integer
fromBytes = BS.foldl' f 0
  where
    f a b = a `shiftL` 8 .|. fromIntegral b
```

If you want to read `Natural` numbers instead of `Integer`s you can give this a more general type signature.

```
-- Read bytes in big-endian order (most significant byte first)
-- Little-endian order is fromBytes . BS.reverse
fromBytes :: (Bits a, Num a) => ByteString -> a
fromBytes = BS.foldl' f 0
  where
    f a b = a `shiftL` 8 .|. fromIntegral b
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to do this in general. I also found the `monadcryptorandom` package. It allows one to bypass the bytestring part of the `Crypto.Random` module entirely and get integers.